# Overwrite parameters in scc ( SecurityContextConstraints )

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I would want to enable **seccomp** on my openshift v4.6 to use **RuntimeDefault**

```
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
```

when i run the command below i can see that i've **allowPrivilegeEscalation** set to **true**

```
$ oc get scc restricted 

allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
allowPrivilegeContainer: false
```

In my deployment yaml file i tried to defined the parameter to false
**securityContext:
allowPrivilegeEscalation: false**

However this does not change anything

Do i've to define a custom **SecurityContextConstraints** to overwrite the parameters ?

Comment: Also have trouble understanding your issue: are you expecting the allowPrivilegeEscalation in the restricted scc to change, because you set allowPrivilegeEscalation to false in your deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question.

Regarding editing a SCC, or creating a new one, see: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/authentication/managing-security-context-constraints.html

Yes, you should always define a new SCC with the changes you want.  It's strongly warned against editing any of the default SCCs in OpenShift.

The SCC controls what can be admitted to the cluster.  If the SCCs available to you define "allowPrivilegeEscalation: true" then you can create pods with this either set to true or false.  If it's set to "false" then you can only create pods with it set to false.

In your deployment configuration you can set a securityContext on either the podSpec or the containerSpec.  Which one are you using?  I recall in my testing there were different behaviours between them, but I can't remember the details off hand.  tldr - if you're using one, try the other.

More importantly, how are you determining whether or not something changed?  Again, in my testing I "oc debug node/ ..." and looked at crictl inspect to observe the effect of that securityContext being changed.